# Javascript record error

Tags: javascript, arrays, design-patterns, syntax

I am having a issue in adding records to arrays, this is where the problem is:

```
  if(score(web[i].content, pattern) > 0){
        scoresArray.push({"url:" + web[i].url + ", score:" + score(web[i].content, pattern)});
    }
```

the error report : SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

This is the array that this peace of code is reading from:

var web = [ {url : "www.lboro.ac.uk",  content : "Loughborough University offers unidegree programmes and world class research." } , {url : "www.xyz.ac.uk",  content : "An alternative University" } , {url : "www",  content : "Yet another University" } ];

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be building one long string inside `{}`. The syntax for an object literal, on the other hand, is `{ key: expression, … }`, where `key` is a string or an identifier.

So try this:

```
if(score(web[i].content, pattern) > 0) {
    scoresArray.push({
        url: web[i].url,
        score: score(web[i].content, pattern)
    });
}
```

You might want to keep a hold of `score`’s return value, too:

```
var item = web[i];
var itemScore = score(item.content, pattern);

if (itemScore > 0) {
    scoresArray.push({
        url: item.url,
        score: itemScore
    });
}
```

Comment: @minty thank you, it worked! Just a general question. How would I go about sorting this in terms of size of itemScore, descending.

Comment: @user2964960: Take a look at [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) – you can pass it a function that subtracts one from the other.